# How do I use SRTM Water Body Data from EarthExplorer?

Tags: earth-explorer

I'm trying to download the SRTM water body data from EarthExplorer and bring it into my QGIS project, but I can't figure out how to use the data they give me.

It gives me 3 file formats to work with: a DBF File and two shapefiles. I load the shapefiles to my project and it tells me it has no CRS. I don't know what to define it as to have it overlay in the right area. The files come with some extra info, but I don't know what I'm looking for in there.

I did find that they send the 4 corners in longitude and latitude, so I thought I would georeference the shapefile, but apparently that's not possible with the normal Georefencer.

Does anyone know how to use this data? the DEMs from EarthExplorer weren't this complicated.

Comment: Any chance you could save the original download archive/zip to a cloud storage (google drive or something similar) and share a link to it? I'm unable to download from EarthExplorer at the moment, it's just returning an error.